# Make Seekbar follow MPAndroidChart X values

Tags: java, android, seekbar, mpandroidchart

I'm working with MPAndroidChart and it's been fine to plot everything. What I need is to have a SeekBar below the chart and be able to highlight different points by moving the SeekBar.

The problem is that the steps of the X values are not regular, not even linear (e.g. `[0,19,25,30,33,47,...]`). I tried making the SeekBar max value the number of points, but the highlight hardly matches the SeekBar position (see image).

[image: Example]

Is there a way to align the MPAndroidChart highlight with the SeekBar position?

---

**EDIT:** Included a naive search method for the nearest x-value. Note that this is not the best approach, but it suits me fine.

```
private int getNearestXValue(int progress) {
    Log.d("PROGRESS", Integer.toString(progress));
    int nearestValue = 0;

    int minimumDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int position = 0;
    for (Entry entry : mData) {
        if (Math.abs((int) entry.getX() - progress) < minimumDistance){
            minimumDistance = Math.abs((int) entry.getX() - progress);
            nearestValue = position;
            position++;
        }
    }

    return nearestValue;
}
```

Comment: will the chart and seekbar match if the x values were linear ? if so, why not use the indexed position of x instead of the x-values for the seeker progress? then do the lookup to get the x-values when trying to draw the line on MPAndroidChart.

Comment: @AngelKoh If the x-values followed a linear step, I could make a function to help the SeekBar follow the values. I didn't understand your suggestion, since the x-values steps are pretty random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try snapping your seekbar to the nearest xValue when the user moves the progressbar.
(e.g. 0 to 9 snaps to 0; 10 to 19 snaps to 19, etc...)
kinda like the following.

```
int[] x_value = {0,19,25,30,33,47,..};
int maxValue = maxOf(x_value);
int minValue = minOf(x_value); 

seekbar.setMax(maxValue -minValue);
```

then at the seekbar onProgressChanged listener

```
onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){

   if(fromUser){
    int x = progress + minValue;
    //snap progress to the nearest x_value
    int nearestX = getNearestXValue(x, x_value);
    seekbar.setProgress(nearestX);

    updateChartline(nearestX);
   }

}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, @AngelKoh. I edited to include the `getNearestXValue` method.